Because stacked depends on stacked, version solving failed
I'm trying to start working with stacked architecture in flutter, and I'm trying to add the stackeed package in my dependency but when I try it gives me an error which says "Because stacked depends on stacked, version solving failed"
I've tried updating my flutter sdk but nothing still worked

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
